# Passing command-line arguments to 'truffle test'

Tags: truffle, testrpc

I have a JS script which I pass to `truffle test` from command line:

```
truffle test my_script.js
```

I would like this script to take an input argument (retrieved via `process.argv[2]`).

Does `truffle support this in some way?

I tried `truffle test my_script.js 0` and received the following error from `truffle`:

```
TypeError: file.match is not a function
    at C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:319282:21
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:319281:21
    at getFiles (C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:319274:16)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:319280:5)
    at Command.run (C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:160766:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:318404:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:22:30)
    at C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:68:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:71:10)
```

I tried `truffle "test my_script.js 0"` and received the following error from `ganache-cli`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJSON' of null
    at C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:90686:25
    at C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:21771:5
    at C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:88595:7
    at C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:7542:16
    at C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:7759:32
    at C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:7534:16
    at C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:88590:9
    at Object.decode (C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:49614:5)
    at C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:88587:20
    at C:\Users\...\cli.node.js:7671:20
```

I tried `truffle test "my_script.js 0"` but then the test doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
0 passing (0ms)
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

`truffle test` does not seem to support such a feature as of this writing.

It takes the following arguments :

`truffle test <test_file> [--compile-all] [--network <name>] [--verbose-rpc]`

So it does not seem to have a way to pass arguments to the test file.

See [command reference](https://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/commands#test) for the details.

One option you may be able to use is (Depending on your use case) it to set an environment variable, and read the environment variable in your test (in place of reading an argument passed to your test)